# Data retrieval with Java's getData() method

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to fully understand how this [Android wheel widget](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-wheel/) works so I can modify it appropriately. In order to do that, I'm going over the code line by line. Right at the beginning of the first document, the activity designated `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` in the manifest, I found the following bit of code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String path = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.android.apis.Path");

if (path == null) {
    path = "";
}

setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(
    this,
    getData(path), 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] { "title" },
    new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }));

getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

I have verified that `path` will always be null because the calling intent, which is the manifest, does not contain a string named `com.example.android.apis.Path`. That means path will always be set to `""`. Yet, `getData(path)` does return the appropriate data, which is:

> [{intent=Intent { cmp=kankan.wheel.demo/.CitiesActivity }, title=Cities}, {intent=Intent { cmp=tw.g35gtw.wheel.demo/tw.g35g.demo.CitiesActivity }, title=Cities}, {intent=Intent { cmp=kankan.wheel.demo/.DateActivity }, title=Date}, {intent=Intent { cmp=tw.g35gtw.wheel.demo/tw.g35g.demo.DateActivity }, title=Date}, {intent=Intent { cmp=kankan.wheel.demo/.PasswActivity }, title=Password}, {intent=Intent { cmp=tw.g35gtw.wheel.demo/tw.g35g.demo.PasswActivity }, title=Password}, {intent=Intent { cmp=kankan.wheel.demo/.SlotMachineActivity }, title=Slot Machine}, {intent=Intent { cmp=tw.g35gtw.wheel.demo/tw.g35g.demo.SlotMachineActivity }, title=Slot Machine}, {intent=Intent { cmp=tw.g35gtw.wheel.demo/tw.g35g.demo.SwipeActivity }, title=Swipe}, {intent=Intent { cmp=kankan.wheel.demo/.TimeActivity }, title=Time}, {intent=Intent { cmp=tw.g35gtw.wheel.demo/tw.g35g.demo.TimeActivity }, title=Time}, {intent=Intent { cmp=kankan.wheel.demo/.Time2Activity }, title=Time 2}, {intent=Intent { cmp=tw.g35gtw.wheel.demo/tw.g35g.demo.Time2Activity }, title=Time 2}]

If anything other than an empty string is fed into `getData()`, it returns nothing. My question is, how does an empty string get the right data? Might the original coder have given `getData()` a default value? If so, where might I find that bit of code so I can modify it?

Also, I can't find a package called `kankan` within the project. Could `kankan.wheel.demo/.CitiesActivity` be an online resource?

Comment: there must be `putExtra(String, String)` method on source activity, can i see code

Comment: Download the source code... https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-wheel/source/default/source

Comment: @Joy Hard

This is the information the log provides about the calling intent:

>09-20 00:39:09.070 6400-6400/? D/WheelDemo: Calling intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=tw.g35gtw.wheel.demo/tw.g35g.demo.WheelDemo }

It appears that the intent is the manifest, which is why `path` is initially null.

Comment: @cricket_007

Thanks, but I have all the source code. However, despite searching through it, I can't find the answers I'm looking for.